# Django - Ajax: sending url params in data

Tags: ajax, django, get, urlconf

I am trying to send a "GET" and "POST" requests to Django server via Ajax. 
First, I provide the URLConf:

```
url(r'^write_to_file/(?P<file_name>.*)/(?P<content>.*)/$',generalFunctions.write_to_file, name ='write_to_file'),
```

Now, the AJAX part. Previously, I used to do it this way (avoiding sending params in data)

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/write_to_file/' + file_name + '/' + content ,
        data: {},
        success: function(data){ 
            alert ('OK');
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("Could not write to server file " + file_name) 
        }
    });
```

Up to a certain moment, I was satisfied by this method, but now it is important for me to pass on file_name and content via the "data" variable and for some reason I get 404 Error.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/write_to_file/',
        data: {'file_name':file_name, 'content':content},

        success: function(data){ 
             alert ('OK');
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("Could not write to server file " + file_name) 
        }
    });
```

Error on server-side:

```
Not Found: /write_to_file/
[15/Apr/2016 14:03:21] "GET /write_to_file/?file_name=my_file_name&content=my_content HTTP/1.1" 404 6662
```

Error on client-side:

`jquery-2.1.1.min.js:4 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/write_to_file/?file_name=my_file_name&content=my_content 404 (Not Found)`

Any ideas why? Is it something wrong with the ajax syntax or it has somehow to do with the URLConf ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
url(r'^write_to_file/(?P<file_name>.*)/(?P<content>.*)/$',generalFunctions.write_to_file, name ='write_to_file'),
```

is now wrong, the url you are sending the post request to is: /write_to_file/

```
url(r'^write_to_file/$',generalFunctions.write_to_file, name ='write_to_file'),
```

is what you'd want i think!

Comment: Well, it no more 404 error, but I have 505 error instead, and the cause is not inside the view itself (I put a breakpoint at the very beginning of the function and the debugger did not reach that point). The error now is TypeError: write_to_file() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)
[15/Apr/2016 14:20:48] "GET /write_to_file/?file_name=my_file_name&content=my_content HTTP/1.1" 500 16010

Comment: This really should be obvious: if you're no longer passing those values in the URL, you need to remove them as parameters to the function.

Comment: Yeah, so were you've defined you write_to_file view you'd need to delete any parameters you may have declared other than the request. e.g. def write_to_file(request, file_name, content): ... should become def write_to_file(request):...

Comment: Well, sorry for being stupid, but if I remove them, then how can I get access from Django view to what I've passed on via Ajax data ?!

Comment: (in view) file_name = request.GET.get('file_name'), and something similar for content, also have a look at request.GET.getlist()

Comment: Thanks for that ! It turns out that in this way I cannot place any regexp restrictions on url variables (like "file_name" and "content" in this case)